# WebView loadURL(url, httpheaders)

Tags: android, webview

I tried the following code to load a URL in an existing `WebView` that I created earlier on.  Unfortunately, the URL site require the Referer header but it is not being set on the request. Has anyone experience this and knows how to properly set the headers?

In my AndroidManifest.xml, I have used `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

```
final Map<String, String> additionalHttpHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
 additionalHttpHeaders.put("Referer", "https://abc.xyz.com");
 webView.loadUrl(url, additionalHttpHeaders);
```

Comment: Wong have you found anything about it?